# magento Soap api is not working on https only

Tags: magento, soap, wsdl

I am running my admin panel in HTTPS for security purpose. Everything is working fine in admin.

But getting this error, while trying to call login method to authenticate where as my secure URL is in HTTPS.

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1

This is working fine in HTTP

```
$username = 'username';
$apiKey = 'apikey';

$api_url_v2 = "https://domain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1"
$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2);
$result = $cli->login(array('username' => $username, 'apiKey' => $apiKey));
```

Comment: Do you have ssl certificated for your site ?

Comment: @sagarumaretiya yes, i have all

Comment: Okay. could you please try in admin system->general->web->Use Secure URLs in Frontend -> yes

Comment: @sagarumaretiya, why try?

Comment: Okay make system->general->web->Use Secure URLs in Frontend -> yes so when request comes as an api call it will find https instead of http so i think you need to make it https

Comment: @sagarumaretiya, Http is not the problem to run soap api, if its http its working fine.only in https its throwing error.

Comment: Have you tried system->general->web->Use Secure URLs in Frontend -> yes or not yet ?

Comment: @sagarumaretiya, to try this we have to wait 1 week for port opening, and roll out

Answer (score 0):

It seems server site issue. Ask your hosting provider. It can be resolved by following steps:

- add a ssl vhost on private ip for www.xyz.com
- reload apache
- Also made a host file entry

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the /tmp directory of all wsdl* files was the solution to our issue.